# How to get Twitter statuses with replies using TweetSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, recursion, twitter, recursive-query

I'm trying to get all Tweets tweeted by me **with replies** (if any).
I'm using TweetSharp and I'm able to get my own tweets but couldn't figure out how to get the replies as well in the same request/response.

Also, I'm able to get all replies/mentions by itself, but in a separate request which would make it very hard to link each reply with it's original Status.

I tried to use the "Exclude Replies" property but it's not making any difference in the response:

```
TimelineTweetsOptions.ExcludeReplies = true;
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this? even with using another library such as LinqToTwitter or anything else?

*I'm coding with ASP.NET C# and TweetSharp v4.0.2*

**Update #1:** ExcludeReplies property works, but only for my own replies to other users.. I still can't get the status with all users' replies.

**Update #2:** I understand I have to use some recursion methods to achieve this, any help?

Comment: The Twitter API itself does not make this easy. If you do a web search for twitter api and conversation you'll see some of the hacks people use to try and rebuild conversations (which is normally replies and replies to replies). A second call is required IIRC. Each tweet should have an InReplyToId which should make it easy to correlate replies to originals even if you have two result sets (linq helps here).

Comment: Basically, you should look at the Twitter API to figure out how you want to do something, then use the equivalent TweetSharp methods. If you can't figure it out from the API, the deficiency is not TweetSharp specific.

Comment: @Yort : I know it's not easy and not provided by Twitter APIs, even if I stored Tweets and Replies in two different tables in DB, I still want help to arrange each tweet with it's replies as a conversation, I couldn't figure the right logic to do that!

Comment: @Yort also, there's `InReplyToStatusId` but as you said its replies and replies to replies so how I can keep track of the original Status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer of my own question, as @Yort said there's no easy way to do it by a single call.

So my solution was to use `InReplyToStatusId` field and track it up until I reach a the root status (since I store all the statuses in my Database).

Ofcourse, I consider a status is a root by having `InReplyToStatusId == 0` or in case it's a Retweet then I won't find the original Tweet in my Database then it's my root status and stop.

Store each status in a List, then order by date desc or asc.